# How to make Rails I18n string partially safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, rails-i18n

How to mark as not safe only the variable that is passed into the translation method, when using `i18n` gem in Ruby on Rails framework?

For example:

```
t(
  'safe', 
  default: 'Unsafe <b>%{unsafe_variable}</b> and safe %{safe_variable}', 
  unsafe_variable: "<script>alert('unsafe');</script>", 
  safe_variable: '<strong>safe</strong>'
)
```

Should return

```
Unsafe <b>&lt;script&gt;alert('unsafe');&lt;/script&gt;</b> and safe <strong>safe</strong>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know in advance which one is safe and which one is unsafe, you can simply use the `h` helper to force escape the unsafe variable.

```
t('safe', default: 'Unsafe <b>%{unsafe_variable}</b> and safe %{safe_variable}', 
  unsafe_variable: h("<script>alert('unsafe');</script>"), 
  safe_variable: '<strong>safe</strong>'
)
```